# How to adjust all the Points in the screen using CImg

Tags: c, cimg

I have to draw Lines which has bigger double values like (3000.00,4500.45).

```
CImg<unsigned char> img(800,800,1,3,20);
img.draw_line( 3000.00, 4500.45, 3478.567, 4500.45, RED);
```

But i want to keep my screen size limited to 800x800

I thought to take Modulus of the Point's coordinates within 800
Like

> 3000.00%800=600

I can fit 600 in my Screen .
But the problem is , CPP does not support modulus of double value .

```
double a = 3000.00;
printf("%lf",a%800.0); //Expected 600 but exception
**Invalid operand of type double,double to binary operator%**
```

How can I fit these large points in my screen using CImg ?

Comment: `CPP` ?? you should add [tag:C++] tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depend on what you want to perform actually :

- If you just want to see the part of the line drawn on your 800x800 image, then do nothing. The `CImg<T>::draw_line()` method implements clipping and it will do this automatically for you.
- If you want to drawn "random" lines on your screen and don't care about the fact that using a modulo on your coordinates will screw up the original line appearance, then you can use a modulo. In your case, it is probably better to first cast your coordinates into `int`, then use the `%` operator afterwards :

`img.draw_line( ((int)x0)%800, ((int)y0)%800, ((int)x1)%800, ((int)y1)%800, RED);`

but be aware that the line that will be drawn has *nothing* to do with the original line: doing modulos is not a clipping method for drawing lines.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer . It didn't appear in my mind that taking modulo will do nothing rather then drawing some random lines .
But , I even don't want to clip my lines .
`Is it possible to scale those lines smaller so that my screen can hold all the lines ?`

Comment: I have found a solution , which can solve my problem just for now .
Let i want to plot points which may have the largest co-ordinate 9999.99
But , my Screen can only show Points up to 800.
So my solution is 
`float scale=9999.99/800;`
`img.draw_line(x0*scale, y0*scale, x1*scale, y1*scale, GREEN); `

Comment: That's it, you need a global normalization of your input values. The best way to do this is to first find the xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax values in all your coordinates, then compute the new values as : `X = (x-xmin)*800/(xmax-xmin)` and `Y = (y-ymin)*800/(ymax-ymin)`.

Answer (score 1):

Operand of `%` remainder operator can't be double (or float) use  [`fmod (double numer, double denom)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) function instead.